# Django on EC2 using RDS

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, rds

I have a Django App running on an EC2 instance and trying to connect to a RDS mysql Database instance.

I have created the RDS database and added a rule to the RDS Security group that allows for EC2 Security Group.

In my `settings.py` file, I have added the HOST to be the RDS EndPoint and the Port to be 3306 - along with the DB name, user and password.

I have installed libmysqlclient-dev, MySQL-python and mysql-client on the EC2 instance.

When I run `./manage.py syncdb`, I get this error:

```
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")*
```

It looks like it is trying to connect to a local mysql server (which of course is not there, since I want it to connect to an RDS).

How can I get past this?

Comment: On the EC2 instance, in the shell, can you connect to mysql using the mysql command line?

Comment: i have not used RDS but do you have to assign it a security group like ec2 and enable access on port 3306 for your ip?

Comment: Did you add the RDS settings to `default` database settings?

Answer (score 0):

You don't set rds in default, or you loading wrong settings file. Python mysql trying to connect with localhost base, through socket (it's when HOST field is empty). You can try print DATABASE['default']['HOST'] in settings, or django shell to check host in settings.